# SQL groupby argmax

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mariadb, argmax

Let there be a table such as this:

| group ID | member ID | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 3 | 3 |
| 0 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 16 | 0 |
| 2 | 21 | 7 |
| 2 | 32 | 4 |
| 2 | 14 | 6 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

The table has three columns, a `group ID`, which uniquely indentifies a certain `group`, a `member ID`, which uniquely identifies `members` inside individual `groups` (globally, `member ID` is not unique), and `value`, which is something we want to maximize inside each group.

The task is to find a `member ID` for each `group ID` which maximizes `value`. That sounds like a simple enough procedure, right?

Well, apparently, it is not. I'm using MariaDB and have tried everything on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556653/is-there-something-equivalent-to-argmax-in-sql), such as

```
select group_id, member_id, value from table x
    join (select max(t.value) as max_v from table t group by group_id) y on y.max_v = x.value;
```

but none of these approaches yielded the correct result.
For completeness, the expected output of the query for the above table would be

| group ID | member ID | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 21 | 7 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

or even

| group ID | member ID |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 21 |
| 3 | 1 |
| ... | ... |

if returning the `value` would cause problems. I'd appretiate any sort of help.

Comment: Your subquery should also return `group_id` which you should also use in the ON clause.

Comment: @forpas Yeah, I seem to have arrived at a solution thanks to you and Rui Costa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can work, if the `group_id, member_id, value' combination is unique.

```sql
SELECT 
  x.group_id, 
  x.member_id,
  x.value
FROM 
  table x
join 
  (SELECT 
    group_id, 
    max(t.value) as max_v 
   FROM table t 
   GROUP BY group_id
  ) y 
ON y.max_v = x.value 
AND y.group_id = y.group_id
```

Comment: You are correct, my mistake. Can you check the updated?

Comment: Happy to help :)